# Polygon Mumbai test net MATIC tokens

Tags: tokens, testnets, polygon, faucets

I am developing a Dapp and I want to test it using the Mumbai testnet but I need many matic tokens. Currently the Mumbai faucet is giving you only 1 MATIC token. Is there a way to obtain some more?

**Note:** My idea is the testnet to be something like stage environment where QA test could be done. I want the testnet because of the polygonscan explorer which is making the tracing of the transaction very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need many MATIC tokens on testnet? Or do you just need something like a hard fork of the main net with all the contract and wallet addresses present there that you can run locally to then test your contracts with the scenarios you want? In a locally run fork of the mainnet you can assign yourself as many test MATIC tokens you need. There's a link on Hardhat that describes mainnet forking at https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/guides/mainnet-forking.html which may allow you an option here.

Comment: It depends, can I use polygonscan to snatch my transactions. I want to use the test net for something like stage environment where QAs can test.

Comment: So if you're doing QA you probably want to automate this, using a script to document the test transaction path so you can repeat this tests over time, so the issue here would be to get the transaciton history. In Hardhat there's documentation for transaction history/logs [here](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-transactions.html) and with Brownie this is documented at [here](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-transactions.html) so you in essence get what Polygonscan would give you as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: My concern is that when testing against forked mainnet with automated test made by me I will test only the testcases I can think of where as if QA do some testing he/she will try every nonsense which they can think of eventually finding some problems. I assume that the QA persons are not technical people that is why I want it to make the interactions with the web as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://buildbear.io/ and create your own Testnet by forking Ethereum, Polygon, Binance, Optimism, Arbitrum, Fantom, and Avalanche chains, allowing you to test your projects on the actual Mainnet state.[image]